# How can we encourage more Questions/Day?

Tags: discussion

Our answer % and visits per day [stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/98617/monero) remains healthy both of which help make Stack Exchange very useful for the community.

At some point there was a GitHub conversation (I cannot find the link at the moment) where a developer suggested that certain open issues would make good material for Stack Exchange. I shared that idea on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5xssvw/suggestion_for_stack_exchange_material/) today.

Frequently questions asked on Reddit and IRC would appear to be more suitable for Stack Exchange.

Please share additional methods of increasing Stack Exchange activity. Currently we have many people that visit Stack Exchange to find answers, but rarely post questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly, the reminders on reddit help. Keep doing those for sure. If people are like me they just get busy and need to be reminded what needs attention.
Other than that, one thing that keeps me from posting questions is worrying that I haven't researched it thoroughly enough first and that the response I'll get will be negative in that regard. I'm trying to find a balance there but I don't believe anyone on this site has been harsh in their answer to any question.